# Multiple Where conditions or Join on same table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL, i need the result set based on each hour difference between two datetime field . For example, The result set is need to be like this

I need to Groupby by USERID, StartDate

I am bit confused about using Sub Query or join between same table. So, help me to get out from this

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| USERID    Date          6to7    7to8    8to9    9to10   10to11 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 119       2016-03-07    5                                      |
| 119       2016-03-10                     18                    |
| 5         2016-03-08    8                                      |
| 5         2016-03-10                             7             |
| 25        2016-03-09               2     20                    |
| 30        2016-03-11                     5                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The table looks like below

```
  ID    UserId         StartDate            EndDate
7494    119    2016-03-07 06:35:55.000      2016-03-07 06:40:55.000
7495    5      2016-03-08 06:02:33.000      2016-03-08 06:10:33.000
7496    25     2016-03-09 07:58:33.000      2016-03-09 08:20:33.000
7497    25     2016-03-09 07:54:20.000      2016-03-09 07:56:20.000
7498    119    2016-03-10 08:35:55.000      2016-03-10 08:53:55.000
7499    5      2016-03-10 09:02:33.000      2016-03-10 09:09:33.000
7500    30     2016-03-11 08:58:33.000      2016-03-11 08:59:33.000
7501    30     2016-03-11 08:54:20.000      2016-03-11 08:58:20.000
```

This is the code I have tried

```
SELECT  UserID, 
        StartDate,
        (SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, CAST(SWITCHOFFSET(TODATETIMEOFFSET(StartDate,      '-00:00'), '+06:00') AS DATETIME),
CAST(SWITCHOFFSET(TODATETIMEOFFSET(EndDate, '-00:00'), '+06:00') AS    DATETIME))
))'HRS6TO7' 
FROM TMCallResultLog 
WHERE  CAST(StartDate AS TIME) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '07:00:00' AND
EndDate IS NOT NULL AND 
StartDate IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY UserID, StartDate
```

Comment: Please add the code that you've tried.

Comment: yes I added @Sefe

Comment: @dineshsns can you elobarate on your output table? what does that values indicate in columns 6 to 7, 7 to 8,etc....are they counts?

Comment: 6to7, 7to8 all are the timings. For Ex: 6:00AM to 7:00 PM, 7:00AM to 8:00 PM and so on @balaji

Comment: @dineshsns I understand that...I am asking about the values present in those columns of your output table...

Comment: Its the Time difference in Minutes between StartDate and EndDate on Particular Hour and Date

Comment: and where are you struck ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called *conditional aggregation*. Also you need to cast StartDate to `date` (to cut off time) before grouping:

```
select
  UserID,
  CAST(StartDate as DATE) StartDate,
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN CAST(StartDate AS TIME) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '07:00:00' AND
      THEN DATEDIFF(...)
      ELSE 0
    END
   ) as [6to7],
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN CAST(StartDate AS TIME) BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '08:00:00' AND
      THEN DATEDIFF(...)
      ELSE 0
    END
   ) as [7to8],
   ...
from ...
where EndDate IS NOT NULL AND StartDate IS NOT NULL 
group by
  UserID,
  CAST(StartDate as DATE)
```